# How to show link only to person logged in?

Tags: php, html, session, post

I have a link that, using jQuery, shows a box to update a user's bio. However, I want that link to only show if the user is logged in, and only on that user's page. So, for example, if I'm logged in, it shows up on my page, but then if I go to a friends page, it doesn't show up so that I don't have to option to change their bio. Here's my code:

```
    <div class="changeBio">
        <?php
            if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
                ?><a href="" id="showBio">Change bio</a><?php
            }
        ?>
    </div>
```

This code will check it the user is logged in, but what should I put in the if statement to check if it's the correct user? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

When each user logs in, they have a unique id from the database where their information is stored. Each friends page is displayed based on these id's, so I only want the link to be displayed on the page of the person who's logged in, and not on their friends page. I've tried 
   if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] && $id != $_GET['id'])
and
   if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] && $id == $_SESSION['id'])
But neither of them work.. In the url of the friends page you're viewing it shows the id of that user as a GET variable if that helps.

Comment: Can you be more explicit? What do you know about the logged in user? Do you store that info in session data?

Comment: What is `$id`? Also, you don't need `if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == true)`. `if ($_SESSION['loggedin'])` suffices because `($_SESSION['loggedin'])` is already a boolean expression. Red herring you might say, but a useful detail to note :)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to include WHO is logged in, not just if they are or not.  You'll need that information to determine which bio to display as well.

Something like this with your data:

```
<div class="changeBio">
    <?php
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == true && $_POST['id'] == $_SESSION['loggedin_userid']) {
        ?><a href="biopage.php?userid='<?php echo $_SESSION['loggedin_userid']; ?>'" id="showBio">Change bio</a><?php
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the ID, user name, or some identifying feature of the user currently logged in within your session data.

Then, you can verify whether or not a specific user is logged in with code akin to

```
if ($_SESSION['currentUserID'] == $idOfTheUserThatTheBioBelongsTo)
    // let the user change the bio
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have another variable $current_user stored in session along with $id as u have mentioned above (which i guess will keep changing from user to user) and then on the page where you need to display the message for current user you can use

```
if($id == $current_user){
 //whatever you want to do
}
```